# How to send url in a click callback function

Tags: jquery

I have a function like so

```
$(function(){
    $("selector").on("click", "selector", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

        //run code here then in the callback send the url.

    });
});
```

basically i don't want to use a setTimeout, but i'd like the log file to finish its log before firing the window.location.href = url;

is this possible from a click event.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Just make the call there and put the location.href call in the callback. What are you unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

```
$(function(){
    $("selector").on("click", "selector", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

            var dfd = $.Deferred();

            dfd
           .done( function(){//log code} )
           .done(function() {
            window.location.href=url
           });

    });
});
```

Comment: var url = $(this).attr("href");
var dfd = $.Deferred();

dfd.done(function(){
 console.log(url);
 DimitriLogEvent(cat, action);  
 alert("test");
})
.done(function(){
 alert("test1");
 window.location.href = url;
});

this isn't firing anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beforeUnload` jQuery event to perform whatever special tricks you have before it moves on to the next page.

```
$('selector').click(function() {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        //run code here then in the callback send the url.
    });
});
```